# Can't get form errors when using crispy forms

Tags: django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm using `django-crispy-forms`, a third party library, in a `Django` project, I would like to customize a form to get the errors at top of the form, but I can't.
This is a snippet of the code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h1>Add New Task</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">{{ form|as_crispy_errors:"bootstrap3" }}</div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">{{ form.project|as_crispy_field }}</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2" id="add-new">
                <a href="{% url 'pomodoro:new-project' %}">Add new</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">{{ form.title|as_crispy_field }}</div>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

The view:

```
def new_task(request):
    form = NewTaskForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return redirect('/pomodoro/home')

    return render(request, 'pomodoro/new-task.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

This is my form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Task


class NewTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['project', 'title',]
```

Comment: Please show your view

Comment: Add `print(form.errors)` before the `return render()` line to show what the errors are.

Comment: nothing printed in the command line.

Comment: Please show your form

Comment: I added the form

Comment: I can't spot the issue. The code looks OK to me.